# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' after converting string to float

Tags: python, web-scraping

Using: Python in Google Collab
Thanks in Advance:
I have run this code on other data I have scraped FBREF, so I am unsure why it's happening now. The only difference is the way I scraped it.
The first time I scraped it:
`url_link = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/Big5/gca/players/Big-5-European-Leagues-Stats'`

The second time I scraped it:

`url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/22/stats/Major-League-Soccer-Stats'`

`html_content = requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')`

`df = pd.read_html(html_content)`

I then convert the data from object to float so I can do a calculation, after I have pulled it into my dataframe:

`dfstandard['90s'] = dfstandard['90s'].astype(float)`
`dfstandard['Gls'] = dfstandard['Gls'].astype(float)`

I look and it shows they are both floats:

10  90s      743 non-null    float64

11  Gls      743 non-null    float64

But when I run the code that as worked previously:

`dfstandard['Gls'] = dfstandard['Gls'] / dfstandard['90s']`

I get the error message "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

I am fairly new to scraping, I'm stuck and don't know what to do next.

The full error message is below:

````
<ipython-input-152-e0ab76715b7d> in <module>()
      1 #turn data into p 90
----> 2 dfstandard['Gls'] = dfstandard['Gls'] / dfstandard['90s']
      3 dfstandard['Ast'] = dfstandard['Ast'] / dfstandard['90s']
      4 dfstandard['G-PK'] = dfstandard['G-PK'] / dfstandard['90s']
      5 dfstandard['PK'] = dfstandard['PK'] / dfstandard['90s']

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _outer_indexer(self, left, right)
    261 
    262     def _outer_indexer(self, left, right):
--> 263         return libjoin.outer_join_indexer(left, right)```
    264 
    265     _typ = "index"

pandas/_libs/join.pyx in pandas._libs.join.outer_join_indexer()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'>
````

Comment: Please post the full error message traceback.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you for your comment. I added the full error message into the OP.

Comment: can you please include a sample of data frame, after doing this `df = pd.read_html(html_content)`?

Comment: @Priya I'm sorry, but I wasn't  100% sure what you meant, so I have attached an image. It's a picture of the data frame that I used. I drop the top column header later on. Please let me know if you need something else. Sorry, new to this site. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m4qnPm94xuPt1ih3pFHmcnRzoouaHrzN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I just tried doing it...I see that you have two columns named "Gls"?..which one are you taking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two `Gls` columns in your dataframe. I think you converted only one `"Gls"` column to float, and when you do `dfstandard['Gls'] = dfstandard['Gls'] / dfstandard['90s']`, the other "Gls" column is getting considered?...

Try stripping whitespace from the column names too

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
df['90s'] = pd.to_numeric(df['90s'], errors='coerce')
df['Gls'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Gls'], errors='coerce')
```

Thus the error.

Comment: I was able to find some code to change the name of the columns that were the same.


```cols = []
count = 1
for column in dfstandard.columns:
    if column == 'Gls':
        cols.append(f'Gls_{count}')
        count+=1
        continue
    cols.append(column)
dfstandard.columns = cols```


Once I changed the calculations to take in the new names it was able to do it. :)

Comment: great!..so the error is fixed right?

Comment: Yes, thank you for assisting in my search for a solution.

Do I need to clicked solved somewhere?

Comment: No, you don't need to click anywhere, saying that it is solved.